# In chocolatey, is is possible to tell that I want autouninstall turned off for this package

Tags: chocolatey

I have a chocolatey package, based on an InnoSetup installer.

The chocolateyInstall.ps1 is very basic:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' # stop on all errors
$toolsDir   = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"

$packageArgs = @{
  packageName   = $env:ChocolateyPackageName
  fileType      = 'EXE'
  file          = Join-Path $toolsDir 'Multigit installer 1.5.1'

  softwareName  = 'Multigit*'

  #silentArgs   = '/VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART /SP-' # Inno Setup
}

Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage @packageArgs
```

I also have a matching chocolateyuninstall.ps1 with mostly default stuff:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' # stop on all errors
$packageArgs = @{
  packageName   = $env:ChocolateyPackageName
  softwareName  = 'Multigit*'
  fileType      = 'EXE'
  silentArgs   = '/VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART /SP-' # Inno Setup
  file          = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IDEMIA\Multigit\Uninstall\unins000.exe'
}

Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage @packageArgs
```

When I uninstall, I get this output:

```
c:\work\packaging\Multigit>choco uninstall multigit -y
Chocolatey v1.2.1
Uninstalling the following packages:
multigit

multigit v1.5.1
Uninstalling multigit...
0
multigit has been uninstalled.
 Running auto uninstaller...
 Skipping auto uninstaller - 'IDEMIA - Multigit 1.5.1' appears to have been uninstalled already by other means.
 multigit has been successfully uninstalled.

Chocolatey uninstalled 1/1 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
```

The problem I have with this is:

- I wonder why I have a line printing a 0
- the auto uninstaller will still run for nothing.

I wonder if it's possible to disable the auto-uninstaller, for this package, to avoid confusing the inexperienced user.

I don't want to turn it off globally for the user, it might be useful for other packages.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder why I have a line printing a 0

The value of 0 comes from the call to `Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage`. That cmdlet returns the exit code that it received from the uninstaller being called, and by the nature of how PowerShell works, it is then outputted.
You may disable that by either doing.

```
$null = Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage @packageArgs
```

or

```
Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage @packageArgs | Out-Null
```

> I wonder if it's possible to disable the auto-uninstaller, for this package, to avoid confusing the inexperienced user.

You can disable the auto uninstaller per package, this can be done by either the package maintainer by adding an empty file called `.skipAutoUninstall` when creating the package, or the user can pass in the argument `--skip-autouninstaller` when uninstalling the package.

In your case, I do not recommend adding the `.skipAutoUninstall` file due to the simplicity of the uninstall script, which will fail if a user has installed the program to a custom location (due to your use of a hard-coded path), or if the software has been uninstalled by other means before the package is uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a couple of ways that you can do this.

The first is driven by the end user of your application.  They could pass in the `--skip-autouninstaller` option to the `choco uninstall` command, as documented here:

https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/uninstall#options-and-switches

> ```
>  --skipautouninstaller, --skip-autouninstaller
> SkipAutoUninstaller - Skip auto uninstaller service when uninstalling. 
>   Overrides the default feature 'autoUninstaller' set to 'True'. Available 
>   in 0.9.10+.
> ```

Or, you as the package maintainer can include an empty `.skipAutoUninstall` file within your package.  As shown here:

https://github.com/chocolatey-community/chocolatey-packages/blob/master/automatic/keepassxc/tools/.skipAutoUninstall

This will inform Chocolatey to skip the autouninstaller for your package.